# Problems with Wifi driver on ASUS TUF Gaming FX504 | Using Debian 10

Tags: debian, wifi, drivers

I'll show you the complete output of `lspci` so you can see which wireless network card this PC has:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 8th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 07)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Skylake PCIe Controller (x16) (rev 07)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 630 (Mobile)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Skylake Processor Thermal Subsystem (rev 07)
00:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Skylake Gaussian Mixture Model
00:12.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH Thermal Controller (rev 10)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH USB 3.1 xHCI Host Controller (rev 10)
00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH Shared SRAM (rev 10)
00:15.0 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH Serial IO I2C Controller (rev 10)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH HECI Controller (rev 10)
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake Mobile PCH SATA AHCI Controller (rev 10)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH PCI Express Root Port (rev f0)
00:1d.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH PCI Express Root Port (rev f0)
00:1d.6 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH PCI Express Root Port (rev f0)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Device a30d (rev 10)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH cAVS (rev 10)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH SMBus Controller (rev 10)
00:1f.5 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH SPI Controller (rev 10)
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP107M [GeForce GTX 1050 Mobile] (rev a1)
02:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Kingston Technologies Device 5008 (rev 01)
03:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
04:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)
```

As you can see, this line shows my wireless network card:

```
03:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
```

Ok so I have tried a lot of ways to try to make my network card work, but I'll repeat again here for example one process that I followed.

### FIRST

I found this repository on github which has all needed for installing this driver.

```
https://github.com/tomaspinho/rtl8821ce
```

If you go down in the readme file, it says that you need to execute 2 commands before installing the driver:

```
sudo apt install bc module-assistant build-essential dkms
```

MY OUTPUT:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
bc is already the newest version (1.07.1-2+b1).
build-essential is already the newest version (12.6).
dkms is already the newest version (2.6.1-4).
module-assistant is already the newest version (0.11.10).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Of course, I get this because I already did this step. Now we go with the second command:

```
sudo m-a prepare
```

MY OUTPUT:

```
Getting source for kernel version: 4.19.0-6-amd64
Kernel headers available in /lib/modules/4.19.0-6-amd64/build
apt-get install build-essential 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
build-essential is already the newest version (12.6).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

Done!
```

Again, I already did this step, no problems found so far.

### SECOND

I found this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vPfLVsyQU_A), and I followed the steps for the installation:

1º `sudo apt update`
MY OUTPUT:

```
Hit:1 http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates InRelease                                          
Hit:2 http://ftp.es.debian.org/debian buster-backports InRelease                                                   
Hit:3 http://ftp.es.debian.org/debian buster InRelease
Hit:4 http://ftp.es.debian.org/debian buster-updates InRelease
Reading package lists... Done                       
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
```

2º `sudo apt install -y dkms git`
MY OUTPUT:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
dkms is already the newest version (2.6.1-4).
git is already the newest version (1:2.20.1-2).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

3º `git clone https://github.com/tomaspinho/rtl8821ce`
MY OUTPUT:

```
Cloning into 'rtl8821ce'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 33, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (33/33), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (25/25), done.
remote: Total 1456 (delta 10), reused 16 (delta 8), pack-reused 1423
Receiving objects: 100% (1456/1456), 5.87 MiB | 4.01 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (782/782), done.
```

4º `cd rtl8821ce`
5º Turn off the wired connection
6º `sudo ./dkms-install.sh`
MY OUTPUT:

```
About to run dkms install steps...
Error! DKMS tree already contains: rtl8821ce-v5.5.2_34066.20190614
You cannot add the same module/version combo more than once.
Module rtl8821ce/v5.5.2_34066.20190614 already built for kernel 4.19.0-6-amd64/4
Module rtl8821ce/v5.5.2_34066.20190614 already installed on kernel 4.19.0-6-amd64/x86_64
Finished running dkms install steps.
```

7º `sudo modprobe 8821ce`
MY OUTPUT:

```
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert '8821ce': Required key not available
```

## BELOW YOU CAN FIND THE SOLUTION TO THIS PARTICULAR PROBLEM

Answer (score 0):

## ANSWER TO MY QUESTION

I found the solution [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/762254/why-do-i-get-required-key-not-available-when-install-3rd-party-kernel-modules). You can go there and check it, but I will sum it up here.

1º `sudo apt install mokutil`
2º `sudo mokutil --disable-validation`
You will be asked for a password, then reboot your laptop and you will be asked your password that you entered. Don't enter the complete password, just the characters that you need and you will be asked.
For example, your password is "12345678", and when you reboot they ask you for the first and third character. You have to enter "1", and "3". When you are done, disable the secure boot.

After all of this, your Wifi should be working.